# Using variables defined in a class in another swift file? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Just a reminder, I'm a complete beginner at this, so the most detail possible would be greatly appreciated!

Anyway, I have a class named Apple. Inside Apple, I have a function called getAppleCalculationCal, inside of that, I have a variable called 'AppCal', AppCal was declared and set inside getAppleCalculationCal. The problem is, I want to use it inside another swift file. Unfortunately, the second swift file, doesn't recognize it when i try to use it doing math.

For reference, here's my code

Apple class and function

```
class Apple {
    var b: Int?

    init() {

    }
    //Calories
    func getAppleCalculationCal() -> Int {
        if let unwrappedB = b {
         var AppCal = unwrappedB * 80
            println(AppCal)
            return AppCal

        }
        else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you don't access `AppCal` directly. You are returning the value of `AppCal` from your `getAppleCalculationCal` method. So all you need to do is save that result.

```
// some other swift file
var apple = Apple()
apple.b = 123
var result = apple.getAppleCalculationCal()
```

One this code runs `result` will hold the value that `AppCal` is inside your posted function.

---

Also starting names with a capital letter is usually reserved for the names of classes or structs. So I would recommend changing that from `AppCal` to `appCal`, which is closer to accepted convention.

Comment: Thanks for the response! If you don't mind answering, whats the point of the 123 after apple.b?

Comment: Well `getAppleCalculationCal` seems to do something with `b`. So I decided to make sure `b` has a value. It's not required for the example to work, as your code would just return zero if it's absent.